# How to create new variable from two existing categorical variables

Tags: r, variables, categorical-data

I need to generate a new variable from two existing dichotomous variables. Example:

```
Var1 = c(1,0,1,0,0)
Var2= c(0,1,1,1,0)
```

and new variable should look like:

```
Var3= c(1,1,1,1,0)
```

Basically, when `var1=1` and `var2=0` then `var3=1`; and so on.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `|`

```
df1$Var3 <- with(df1, +(Var1|Var2))
df1$Var3
#[1] 1 1 1 1 0
```

---

Or sum and then create logical

```
df1$Var3 <- with(df1, as.integer((Var1 + Var2) > 0))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Var1 = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), Var2 = c(0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

For this, you can also use:

```
pmax(Var1, Var2)

[1] 1 1 1 1 0
```